# Adding more variables to python class in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code:

```
DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)

class Author(ndb.Model):
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    """picture = ndb.BlobProperty(indexed=False)"""

class MapPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):  
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                         DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greetings_query = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
        greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

        user = users.get_current_user()

        template_values = {
            'user': user,
            'user_mail': user.email(),
            'greetings': greetings,
            'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
            'def_name': DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mappage.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                          DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = Author(
                  identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                  email=users.get_current_user().email())

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        """greeting.picture = self.request.get('picture')"""
        greeting.put()

        query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
        self.redirect('/mappage?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))
```

Basically, the class Guestbook stores the Greeting into the datastore and MapPage retrieves it.

However, whenever I add the code within the comments, i.e.

```
picture = ndb.BlobProperty(indexed=False)
```

to the class Greeting and

```
greeting.content = self.request.get('picture')
```

to the class Guestbook, the code fails to run. I have tried changing picture to StringProperty also but it still does not work.

Comment: You need to include the actual error.  "fails to run"to could due a range of errors, even basic syntax errors such as incorrect use of whitespace.

Comment: on the webpage it shows internal server error

Comment: The logs on your dev console (or on the appengine console dashboard if you already deployed your app) usually give more details than just 'internal server error'. You could update your question with the relevant logging.

Comment: File "/base/data/home/apps/s~map-buddy/3.386471655134662017/main.py", line 66
    picture = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Works now! Thanks alot